Issues with Web Scraping Automation in Python Using Selenium
I’m having trouble with my ETL process. Let me explain my problem, I have this code:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome( options = options )

######################## WEBSCRAPING 
table = None
attempts = 0
max_attempts = 1000
wait_time = 10

while not table and attempts < max_attempts:
    driver.get("https://www.congreso.gob.pe/pleno/congresistas/?=undefined&m1_idP=13")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    attempts += 1
    if not table:
        print(f"Tabla no encontrada. Intento {attempts}/{max_attempts}. Reintentando en {wait_time} segundos...")
        time.sleep(wait_time)
    else:
        print("Tabla encontrada.")

if table:
    headers = [th.text.strip() for th in table.find_all('tr')[0].find_all('th')]  
    data = [[td.text.strip() for td in row.find_all('td')] for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
else:
    print("No se encontró ninguna tabla después de múltiples intentos.")
    driver.quit()
    exit()

The output is the table of this link
print(df.head(3))





Apellidos y Nombres
Grupo Parlamentario
e-mail





Acuña Peralta María Grimaneza
ALIANZA PARA EL PROGRESO
gacuna@congreso.gob.pe



Acuña Peralta Segundo Héctor
HONOR Y DEMOCRACIA
sacunap@congreso.gob.pe



So, I'm trying to automate this process in other environment (without graphical interface). For that reason, I want to add these options:
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument( '--incognito' ) 
options.add_argument( '--headless' )  

Finally, my code (Before ####WEBSCRAPING) will be:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument( '--incognito' ) 
options.add_argument( '--headless' )  
driver = webdriver.Chrome( options = options )

######################## WEBSCRAPING...

But when I try to execute this, Python simply doesn't recognize the table and my code end the loop without the data frame.
Can anyone help me? I want to maintain the options to disable graphic interface.

Python simply doesn't recognize the table Show us the actual result from the code, so we don't have to guess what this means.

Just this: "Tabla no encontrada. Intento 1/1000. Reintentando en 10 segundos...
Tabla no encontrada. Intento 2/1000. Reintentando en 10 segundos...
….
Tabla no encontrada. Intento 1000/1000. Reintentando en 10 segundos...
No se encontró ninguna tabla después de múltiples intentos.
"

The output is the table of this link If you're getting output, then the table was found.  So I don't understand why you say the table was not recognized...?

Not positive but I found when running headless, a lot of the times the page was different. i.e. a prompt to accept cookies or something similar. A hack I used was to save the raw html when running headless to a file and manually inspect it to ensure the content was the same.

Finally, I could do it with these aditional options:
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("accept-language=es-ES,es;q=0.9")
options.add_argument("accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br")
options.add_argument("referer=
https://www.google.com/")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')

Thanks!
